# Cannot find interface declaration for 'RealmSwiftObject', superclass of

Tags: swift, realm, carthage, swift5

I had been using Swift 5 on Mojave 10.4.3 for a few weeks without a problem. Suddenly one of my projects stopped compiling with the error message in the title of this question. After searching and experimenting I found a solution to the issue, and am answering my own question. **This problem is particularly heinous (i.e.: you can spend a lot of time going down blind alleys) since it didn't occur in other projects which are successfully using the Frameworks compiled using Carthage 0.32**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Carthage 0.32 to create the Realm and RealmSwift frameworks.
After searching I was able to find a solution that worked for me.
 [(RealmCocoa Issue 3073)](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3073)  Thanks to jweg29 at github for the solution.

EDIT: See comment below from Larme. One should **use Carthage 0.33 or above for Swift 5**.

I am posting the answer here since it is not obvious that the error is due to an outdated (only slightly) version of carthage.

In the terminal, type:

```
brew upgrade carthage
```

cd to the directory containing your Cartfile file, and rebuild. For me this meant typing:

```
carthage update --platform ios
```

Replace the existing Realm and RealmSwift frameworks in your projects with the freshly created ones, clean (I used Shift-Option-Command-K to be sure) and you should be able to rebuild your project.

Comment: Carthage 0.33 should be used for Swift5 (and yet, could have some issue). I think that your issue is due to the a fix on Realm (cf. https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/commit/fb9e8bc4448bdc4e7ab4fb36cff4ee676102a9e8#diff-0b83f9dedf40d7356e5ca147a077acb4) more info there: https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/2758

Comment: Thank you for the info.  I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Today is the first time I've ever come back to my own question for the answer. I grabbed the appropriate replacement frameworks and am on my way again! I knew I had seen this issue before!